# How can I get the sound that played when tapping the built-in textbox of windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am customizing a keypad, so I need to play a sound when the user is tapping just like the built-in textbox keypad does. Due to the fact that there is no system API for accessing the sound, I ask for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for the specific sound file, or for a mechanism to play any sound?

Comment: Please specify whether or not you want the sound that is played when a key is pressed played when the textbox is played.

Comment: Tilt your laptop microphone really close to your phone....

Comment: It'll be good to have the sound file. You brilliant guys can teach me how to get it or provide me with the file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that there are at least 9 different sounds that the SIP makes when different keys are pressed. It's not just a single sound.

The sounds that are played have not been made publically available. (Officially)